# Returning the type of an inherited class

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Consider:

```
class BasicType
{
    public BasicType() { }
    public T Save<T>() where T : BasicType
    {
        BasicType b = DataContext.Save(this); //Returns a BasicType
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), b);
    }
}

class DerivedType : BasicType
{
    public DerivedType(BasicType b) { }
}

public static void Main()
{
    DerivedType d = new DerivedType();
    d = d.Save<DerivedType>();
}
```

This works, but being forced to specify the type each time I call Save is a drag.
Is there some way to change the BasicType.Save method such that it will always return an instance of the actual type (derived or base) of the instance on which Save is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your definition of `BasicType` so that you're forced to provide the type of `T` at the point of inheritance.

Something like this:

```
class BasicType<T> where T :  BasicType<T>, new()
{
    public BasicType() { }
    public T Save() 
    {
        T b = new T();
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), b);
    }
}

class DerivedType : BasicType<DerivedType>
{
    public DerivedType() { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedType d = new DerivedType();
        d = d.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe this didn't occur to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Generics are not needed in this case.

I think this should be enough:

```
public BasicType Save()
{
     BasicType b = DataContext.Save(this); //Returns a BasicType
     return (BasicType)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType(), b);
}
```

Anyway you should be carefull with this as the inherited classes may not have the expected constructor.

Is better to override the save method, or at least the specific part.

Comment: I don't think that meets the OP's condition of: "always return an instance of the actual type (derived or base) of the instance on which Save is being called"

Comment: I initially rejected this idea and wrote a long-winded solution. Now I see it written though, it's clear it will work. The generics aren't needed. +1.

Comment: @Baldrick, if `Save` is invoked via `DerivedType` then `this.GetType()` will return `DerivedType`. So it should work.

Comment: @DavidArno: The instance will *be* an instance of the derived class, but will be returned *as* a `BasicType` object. I understood that the OP wanted the return type to be of the derived type. For example, the OP's code does `d = d.Save<DerivedType>();` where d is of type `DerivedType`. This will not work without an explicit cast, as it is a downcast to a more derived type.

Comment: @Baldrick, it's only casting it to `BasicType` to reassure the compiler that the type will be suitable to return. Casting doesn't change the type of a reference type.

Comment: @DavidArno: The return type of `Save` is, and always will be, `BasicType`. Sure, internally it's a `DerivedType`, but surely any code that uses that return value will have to do a cast if it wants to treat it as a more derived type? The compiler has no idea what's been returned - the call to `Save` could give back many possible actual types. The method contract only guarantees it'll be *something* that is a `BasicType`.

Comment: This is a great answer, +1 but Baldrick was right. I was trying to find an answer that wouldn't require a cast everytime I call the method, as I use it quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
    class BasicType
    {
        public BasicType() 
        { 
        }

        protected virtual T Save<T>()
        {
            BasicType b = DataContext.Save(this); //Returns a BasicType

            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), b);
        }
    }

    class DerivedType : BasicType
    {
        public DerivedType(BasicType b) 
        { 
        }

        public DerivedType Save()
        {
            return base.Save<DerivedType>();
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        DerivedType d = new DerivedType(new BasicType());
        d = d.Save();
    }
```